# Jasmine Karma calling Login component in angular 5

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine karma test cases. I try to write the karma test case for login component. In that clicking, the submit button is not calling the onSubmit method in the component.ts file

**login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.data.username, this.data.password)
      .delay(1000)
      .subscribe(data => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data.token));
        if (this.urlDirect !== null) {
          window.location.href = this.sharedService.baseUrl + '/' + this.urlDirect;
        } else { this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']); }

      },
        error => {
          this.submitted = false;
          setInterval(() => {
            this.spinnerlogo = false;
          }, 1000);
          let i = 0;
          const timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.errorDiagnostic = 'Incorrect username or password.';
            i++;
            if (i === 10) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              this.spinnerlogo = false;
              this.errorDiagnostic = null;
            }
          }, 500);

        });

  }
```

**login.component.spec.ts**

```
it(`entering value in username and password input controls`, () => {
    userNameEl.nativeElement.value = 'admin';
    passwordEl.nativeElement.value = 'admin';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('after entering value the button should enabled and click Action should happen', () => {
    submitEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null)
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
    expect(comp.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled;
    // const loginButtonSpy = spyOn(comp, 'onSubmit');
    // submitEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    // expect(loginButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```